# C# Using any type of object as function parameter

Tags: c#, .net

I want to make an animator class in C# that will perform some effects on objects (like sliding them right/left, changing their opacity, etc.)
And I wonder if it is possible to call a function with any type of object as a parameter instead of having overloaded functions: one for labels, another for pictureBoxes and another one for panels.

Comment: You probably don't want *any* kind of object - what would it meant to change the opacity of an int, for instance? You want to provide the function with only an object that it makes sense to call it on, which in this case is a Control.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I actually meant to work on Controls. Case solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Use a common base type. In your case this is probably Control

Answer (score 2):

Your animator method will need to accept `Control` instances, where `Control` is the base class of any control.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. You can use the generic type  `MyFunction<T>()`
2. You can use object and figure out casting within the method.

I'd recommend the first option.  Lots more info about it here on stack overflow and also on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk36dx2.aspx)